# No qualifying bean of type available in SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When running my SpringBoot application, I am getting this error:

> An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.experimental001.Repositories.BookRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} -> [Help 1]

I have read through many posts regarding this error but none of them seem to fix my problem.

I have tried adding the @Controller annotation but it doesn't seem to fix the bean problem.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable findAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/title/{bookTitle}")
    public List findByTitle(@PathVariable String bookTitle) {
        return bookRepository.findByTitle(bookTitle);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Book findOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Book not found", null));
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Book create(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        bookRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Book not found", null));
        bookRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Book updateBook(@RequestBody Book book, @PathVariable Long id) {
        if (book.getId() != id) {
            throw new BookIdMismatchException("error");
        }
        bookRepository.findById(id).
                orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Book not found", null));
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }
}
```

Simple Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    String appName;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository

public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    public List<Book> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

Pom:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application File:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = BookRepository)

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might need to add the following to the main app class:

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "Package where the repository is located”)

Looks like your repository is in a different packer and spring context is not able to pick it up when starting up.

Please refer this doc: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanningfor

Comment: Should this annotation be added to my Book Repository class?

Comment: No this should be added to the mail application class where you have @SpringBootApplication. Also once you use component scan you have to specify other components that you want to scan

Comment: I added this to my main application class: @ComponentScan(basePackages = com.example.experimental001.BookRepository). But I am getting this error:  experimental001/src/main/java/com/example/experimental001/Application.java:[13,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class experimental001
[ERROR]   location: package com.example

Comment: Can you try just having the package name?

Comment: Just tried. Error: "Can't find symbol BookRepository". Does it need to be BookRepository.java?

Comment: No usually it’s just the package name. We don’t need to add “BookRepositpry” should just be “.com.example.experimental001”

Comment: Ok. I am going to update the post with my application file.

Comment: Also is you main application file in the root folder? Usually that solves the problem.

Comment: I fixed it by including this: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"BookController","BookRepository"})

Comment: If you add it to be root package you won’t need to o add @ComponentScan and if you use ComponentScan you just need the name of the package I.e. @ComponentScan(basePackageClass=“.com.example.experimental001” I’ll try to see if find something. Can you please share your folder structure?

Comment: The folder structure I used is odd. The controllers, repositories, etc are all placed in their own folder. Aside from that, my folder structure follows that generated by Spring Initializr.